# SSD + HDD RAID 0 Performance?

Tags: raid0

the purpose is to get the max space and the best performance

is it possible to merge **two drives** one is `hdd` and the other is `ssd`
into one partition using `raid 0` ?

and do it provide good performance ?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Of course, but with a RAID0, you will only use the same size on the HDD as is the SSD, which will usually be smaller.

Will it provide good performance? Obviously not, except in edge cases where you read/write only from a fast stripe on the SSD. The slow stripes will severely impact the performance of the whole array. On average, you might end up with a performance boost, but it will be relatively small, depending on your specific workload.

That being said, there are a number of approaches you can take to actually improve the performance with this set:

- Use the fast disk as cache (including both software and hardware [hybrid drives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_drive))
- Use it to store the file system metadata
- Use it as part of a more global [hierarchical storage architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_storage_management).

Comment: i have installed the os on a ssd but i have remain two drives, one is hdd and the other is ssd. so what would be better : 1- use only hdd. 2- use hdd and ssd (raid 0) ?

Comment: Use SSD and HDD separately is the best option.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen i would like to have one partition